# Trimming of tRNA precursors

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology, rna, splicing

From Molecular Biology of the Cell (4th edition) by Bruce Alberts et al. (Chp 6, Pg 338) :

> Both bacterial and eucaryotic tRNAs are typically synthesized as
>   larger precursor tRNAs, and these are then trimmed to produce the
>   mature tRNA. In addition, some tRNA precursors (from both bacteria and
>   eucaryotes) contain introns that must be spliced out.

What's the difference between the two statements (and between trimming and splicing) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trimming = removing RNA sequences from one end.

[image]

[Splicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_splicing) = removing introns and joining exons back together.

[image]